# API design: Hide transitive API

Tags: java, module, api-design

I'm building a set of Android modules with a fixed API that depends on other internal modules. Gradle introduced a nice (build-time) feature here to separate dependencies from those internal modules into two categories:

- `api` - those modules are "API" and transport their dependencies further up the dependency stack (e.g. because their API is referenced in the other API as well)
- `implementation` - those modules are a pure implementation detail, are not part of the API of the implementing module

Gradle uses this mainly to speed up builds, because if the implementation dependency of some module changed, it's API stays constant and thus dependent modules don't need to be recompiled. [This blog post sums it up nicely](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa).

Now when I publish my modules, obviously both the `implementation` and `api` dependencies become regular Maven dependencies in the sense that even the internal modules will transitively "leak" inner API to code that only implements the outer API.

I know that there is probably no way of properly handling this issue and I guess over time people developed different workarounds to cope with the situation, like for example creating "fat" libraries that include the internal dependencies, but hide them via package-visibility or the like, but this is not the way I can go - since my modules are really modules in the sense that they can and should be consumed separately (and eventually be combined with each other), I cannot handle the complexity of creating fat libraries like "moduleA+moduleB", "moduleA+moduleC", aso.

So, what do other people do to remedy this problem? What are other usable workarounds? I have the feeling that a cross-module group visibility modifier is missing, something that tells implementing code "You can only use this class when you're in the same Maven group, even though it's public".

Ideas?

Comment: If it's Android, Java 9 is not an option, is it? Sounds to me like Jigsaw might make possible what you're looking for.

Comment: Interesting, could you give me more details on this?